# disable button on ajax username request

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jquery to check if a username is in use before submitting the registration form. The username check works fine. However, I want to disable the submit button if the username is not-available. This is my code. It works the first time: if username unavailable the button is disabled. But once a username is unavailable any username after that which IS available still leaves the submit button disabled. How can I get the button to become enabled without having to refresh the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#username").keyup(function (e) {

    //removes spaces from username
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

    var username = $(this).val();
    if(username.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

    if(username.length >= 4){
        $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.post('check_username.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
            if(data == '<img src="imgs/available.png" /> Username Available'){
        $("#sumbit").attr("disabled", false);
          $("#user-result").html(data);
                }else{
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
                     $("#user-result").html(data);
                }
        });
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

check_username.php looks like this:

```
//sanitize username
$username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//check username in db
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

//return  count
$username_exist = mysqli_num_rows($results);

    if($username_exist) {
    die('<img src="imgs/not-available.png" /> Username Not Available');
}else{
    die('<img src="imgs/available.png" /> Username Available');
}
```

html submit looks like this:
   html input is

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="special" name="submit"  
value="Register" />
```

Comment: use removeAttr. `$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");`

Comment: still disabled after a username is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove disable using : `$("#sumbit").removeAttr("disabled");`

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#username").keyup(function (e) {

    //removes spaces from username
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

    var username = $(this).val();
    if(username.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

    if(username.length >= 4){
        $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.post('check_username.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
            if(data == 'Available'){
          $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
          $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/available.png" /> Username Available');
                }else{
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
                     $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/not-available.png" /> Username Not Available');
                }
        });
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

**check_username.php** looks like this:

```
//sanitize username
$username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//check username in db
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

//return  count
$username_exist = mysqli_num_rows($results);

    if($username_exist) {
    die('NotAvailable');
}else{
    die('Available');
}
```

Comment: still disabled after a username is unavailable

Comment: add code before if condition and let me know what is in alert :: alert(data == '<img src="imgs/available.png" /> Username Available');

Comment: when username available it says true. when username unavailable it says false.

Comment: seems to be that once the button has been disabled it stays disabled even when username is available. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have live/demo url so that i can check

Comment: I have update php file code and jquery file code.. please check that and let me know

Comment: Have updated. Sorry to say that it still remains disabled. Anything I need to do with html input? I've updated my question with the html input

Comment: hi, i have update code : try $("#submit").attr("disabled", false); instead of $("#sumbit").removeAttr("disabled");. I have check in your console and it work

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`:

```
$("#sumbit").prop("disabled", false);
```

See [jQuery documentation about `prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: still disabled after a username is unavailable